# "password": [ "This field is required." ]

Tags: django-rest-framework, postman

[image]

I have tried to login in my account via postman and I got an error with my password field. therefor I coudn't being authenticated

Comment: You are encoding the values in the URL, so you encode these as if it was a GET request. You nee to alter the items in the body.

Comment: Select the `body` tab instead of Params and add `{ 'username': <your_username>, 'password': <your_pwd>` to it. Should work. The POST request is expecting a JSON body if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would most likely use query params on `GET` methods when you have an endpoint that is doing some sort of searching e.g. /search/?account_no=2514233552. You wouldn't want to use it on a login endpoint which is a `POST` request it's bad practice. The answer to your question you can use:

**Option 1 - use formdata**

[image]

**Option 2 - use raw json**
[image]